# expression for capturing aligned, fixed width fields of integers with failure on invalid succeeding characters

Tags: python, regex

### The main goal

The desired regex should fail for a given fixed width field if THE CONTENTS OF THE ENTIRE FIELD does NOT match the pattern of:

- an integer
- non-zero
- optional +/- signs
- optional padding in front (e.g., `'    1'`)

My current pattern succeeds in the case that *any* front portion matches the pattern. However it should fail unless the entire string matches this pattern.

Some examples of the kind of strings that *should* match (for a field of width 5; all match results are 5 characters long):

```
'12345' # matches up with '12345'
'+2345678' # matches up with '+2345'
'-2345678' # matches up with '-2345'
' +2345678' # matches up with ' +234'
```

My current attempt looks like this, which works for all of the above examples:

```
>>> re.match('(?= *[[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*]?)(?P<X>.{5})', ' +2-345678').group('X')
' +2-3' # should not work here!
```

However I want the expression to fail on the above match attempt due to the fact that the pattern found in the look ahead is interrupted by a non-integer character; in this case, `-`.

An additional string that is causing a problem is the following one, which should also fail:

```
'     1'
```

This one should fail because there are five spaces at the front prior to the integer. Currently the expression allows any number of spaces. I understand this is because `' *'` allows any number of spaces to occur, but it is not solved by doing `' {0,5}'` instead (results in a match for `'     '`).

An additional example that ought to fail:

```
'    +1'
```

In this case, the numerical character does not appear until the sixth position. Therefore the field of width 5 should not produce a match because the matching string `'....+'` ( where dots are spaces) isn't a valid integer.

### Some more details

Since "why do you want to do this?" is a typical question around here:

I have line types from a file containing fields of various specified lengths.

Sometimes the line fields are right-aligned, sometimes left-aligned (with the remaining characters padded with spaces). Sometimes fields contain integers (with optional +/- signs), sometimes floats OR integers (with optional +/- and optional decimals), and sometimes an arbitrary string. And for some of these fields, the entire field is allowed to be spaces, while for others they are not allowed to be empty.

All of the above details for any given field are known in advance. That is, for any specific line definition (ie combination of fields described above), I know in advance the order of each field in the line, its width, and the kind of information it contains (int, float, float OR int, or any string), including whether or not it is allowed to be blank.

What I am attempting to do is write a single regex for each line definition with pattern labels (using the `(?P<NAME>EXPR)` syntax) so the results can be accessed by name, like so:

```
m = re.match('(?P<SOMELABEL>SOME_PATTERN)', 'SOME_STRING')
m.group('SOMELABEL')
```

I am having trouble finding a way to prevent my regex from succeeding for a number of these field types and for a number of edge cases that I want it to fail, including the above case.

Comment: I would suggest you look at pyparsing. This product makes it easy to limit the length of a grammatical entity such as an integer or a float. You can name entities and combine them to form larger entities such as different species of lines.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble extracting your question from this wall of text. There's too much information that isn't related to your question in an obvious way, and other essential information is missing. For example when you say the match should "fail if the total length is not 5", the length of _what_ exactly needs to be 5? Is all of this really necessary to describe your problem? Does it matter if some of your data is left-aligned or an integer? As far as I can tell, your problem seems to be to write a regex that only matches text of a certain length.

Comment: If it helps, a recipe for checking the length of an expression would be `(?=.{LENGTH}(.*))EXPRESSION(?=\1)`. For example in `(?=.{3}(.*))\d+(?=\1)`, the `\d+` would always match exactly 3 digits.

Comment: @Rawing did a heavy revision. i am attempting to use an approach inspired by your suggestion but i'm still not getting the desired failure for things like ` -1-4`. see what you can make of the question now.

Comment: What should be the output for `____-4`? where `_` denotes a space character.

Comment: @revo That one should be a failed match because the first five characters don't include a valid integer representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recipe you can use to force a regex expression to match a certain number of characters:

```
(?=.{LENGTH}(.*))EXPRESSION(?=\1$)
```

Example:

```
>>> # match 5 digits followed by "abc"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?=.{5}(.*))\d+(?=\1$)abc')
>>> pattern.match('12345abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='12345abc'>
>>> pattern.match('123456abc')
>>>
```

If we combine this with a regex for non-zero integers padded with spaces on either side (`\s*[+-]?0*[1-9]\d*\s*`), it passes all the given test cases:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?=.{5}(.*))\s*[+-]?0*[1-9]\d*\s*(?=\1$)')
>>> pattern.match('12345').group()
'12345'
>>> pattern.match('+2345678').group()
'+2345'
>>> pattern.match('-2345678').group()
'-2345'
>>> pattern.match(' +2345678').group()
' +234'
>>> pattern.match(' +2-345678')
>>> pattern.match('     1')
>>>
```

### What is this sorcery?

Let's take a closer look at this recipe:

```
(?=.{LENGTH}(.*))EXPRESSION(?=\1$)
```

First, the lookahead `(?=.{LENGTH}(.*))` skips `LENGTH` characters with `.{LENGTH}`. Then `(.*)` captures all the remaining text in group 1. In other words, we've captured all the remaining text minus the first `LENGTH` characters.

Afterwards, `EXPRESSION` matches and (hopefully) consumes exactly `LENGTH` characters.

Finally, we use `(?=\1$)` to assert that capture group 1 matches. Since group 1 contains all remaining text minus `LENGTH` characters, this will only match if `EXPRESSION` has consumed exactly `LENGTH` characters. We have thus forced `EXPRESSION` to an exact length of `LENGTH` characters.

Comment: This is really fantastically fiendish! Thanks for the detailed explanation it was very helpful.

Comment: This is a regex that requires a look ahead match to the end of the string if using dot-all (or eol if not) every time it matches. The overhead is exponentially tremendous on large strings with lots of matches.

Comment: @x15 Is it really? `.*` consumes everything in a single step, and `(?=\1$)` also succeeds or fails in at most 2 steps. I don't see any tremendous overhead.

Comment: Tremendous overhead. The marks for a 127,000 byte string `Regex1:   (?=.{5}(.*))\s*[+-]?0*[1-9]\d*\s*(?=\1$)
 Options:  < m >
 Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1 )
 Matches found per iteration:   110
 Elapsed Time:    45.97 s,   45965.86 ms,   45965860 µs
 Matches per sec:   239
 Regex2:   (?=.{5}(.*))\s*[+-]?0*[1-9]\d*\s*(?=\1$)
 Options:  < s >
 Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1 )
 Matches found per iteration:   112
 Elapsed Time:    19.12 s,   19120.79 ms,   19120795 µs
 Matches per sec:   585`

Comment: Btw, the pattern needs either the _Multi-line_ or the _Dot-all_ option. Not both, but absolutely needs one or the other. This is an example that shows extreme latency when using a `.*$` ending segment within a backtracking prone beginning segment. Be careful not to use this lethal combination. Note that when the string doubles in size with the same number of matches, the time taken also doubles in size.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your current Regular Expression:

1. Additional brackets (which will match a field like `[2345678`)

   ```
   (?= *[[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*]?)(?P<X>.{5})
        ^                ^
   ```
2. Not applying rule #1 *not integers* strictly

Fixing both will result in a shorter, working regex:

```
(?= {0,4}[+-]?[1-9]\d*$)(?P<X>.{5})
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tF5SPe/1)

### Update

According to more clarifications by comments you need a little modification on mentioned regex:

```
^(?= {0,4}[+-]?[1-9]\d*$)(?P<X>.{4}\d)
                               ^^^^^^
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tF5SPe/2)

Comment: This regex doesn't strictly force the integer to be 5 characters long. Instead, it checks if a valid integer can be matched (with no length restriction), and then consumes the next 5 characters. This can lead to unexpected matches, like `....+1` (where `.` is a space).

Comment: I don't see any requirements that state *integer of length 5* @Rawing

Comment: To be clear: `'....+5'` should NOT produce a match because the first five characters by itself isn't a valid integer (even ignoring the padding). The integer itself need not be five characters long, the string containing the integer is always five characters long.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of changing `.{5}` to `.{4}\d`. Please check update. @RickTeachey

Comment: This idea works well too for the specific problem I gave. The other answer more easily adapts to the various other complicated field types I have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Although the larger problem I have to solve is a little bit more complicated, the solution to the specific issue of how to limit matches to fields of fixed width in the context of a larger string turns out to be somewhat simple using some additional features of the `re` module, i.e. the optional `pos` and `endpos` arguments of the `fullmatch` method.

Ignoring the issue of the field width momentarily: for arbitrary length integers, exclusive of 0, and which therefore cannot start with 0 but can optionally start with + or - signs, and ignoring up to four spaces of padding up front, we can compile this expression for later use:

```
>>> r = ' {0,4}(?P<X>[[-+]?[1-9][0-9]*]?)'
>>> c = re.compile(r)
```

Now we use the `fullmatch` method of the compiled object to match at any arbitrary position in a longer string. Like so:

```
>>> starting_pos = 5
>>> s = '    a    1'
>>> c.fullmatch(s, pos=starting_pos, endpos=starting_pos+5).group('X')
'1'
```

The `fullmatch` method will reliably fail unless the entire partial string is matched, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the question. Regex is not so complex, but it can be applied to complex problems in discrete ways. A good foundation is not poisoning the question with a regex that is extremely in error (or contradicts the explanation).  These are separate clauses in the regex `[[-+]?` and `[1-9]` and `[0-9]*` and `]?`